# Setting build number format conditionally

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I'm using the YML file and i'm trying to set the build number format using the following snippet, but I'm not quite sure how to get the `Build.SourceBranch' into the formatting.

I've tried to use $(Build.SourceBranch) ... (Build.SourceBranch) and Build.SourceBranch

I'm attempting to set the output to look like

`20190220-create-yaml.2` etc for when it's a feature feature branch.

and just `20190220.3` when it's a master branch.

```
variables:
    ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'master') }}: 
      branchSuffix: ${{ format('-{0}', $(Build.SourceBranch)) }}
    ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'master') }}: 
      branchSuffix: ''

name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(branchSuffix)$(Rev:.r)
```

Comment: Try something like `branchSuffix: -${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}` in line3.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you should use `Build.SourceBranchName` instead of `Build.SourceBranch`.  Check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables). If it's one git repos,  Build.SourceBranch=>refs/heads/master and Build.SourceBranchName=>master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lance Li mentioned, use `Build.SourceBranchName` instead of `Build.SourceBranch`. Additionally, in `format` function use `Build.SourceBranchName` variable through `variables` function:

```
variables:
    ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}: 
      branchSuffix: ${{ format('-{0}', variables['Build.SourceBranchName']) }}
    ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}: 
      branchSuffix: ''

name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(branchSuffix)$(Rev:.r)
```

If you want to use `$(Build.SourceBranch)`, add to comparing value `refs/heads`:

`ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')`