# Howto: Allow run time selection build artifact in Azure DevOps YAML pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm able to include the latest version of the artifact published by another pipeline (AppCIPipline) into my YAML pipeline using [Conditional insertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion):

```
name: '$(Build.SourceBranchName)-$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)'
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: AppBuildToDeploy # Required when source == Specific
      source: App_Master_CI
      branch: master
      # buildToDeploy is a pipeline variable
      ${{ if ne(variables['buildToDeploy'], '') }}:
        version: $(buildToDeploy)  #let's leave it blank from the pipeline
      project: NewHorizon
      trigger: none

pool: 'Matrix' # Self hosted agent on a windows server

steps:

- download: 'AppBuildToDeploy'
  patterns: '*_BuildScripts.zip'
  displayName: 'Download Specified Artifacts'
```

I'm getting the following error: " A template expression is not allowed in this context"

Is there a way to get the version number from the user at run time and use the version, if supplied, else default to the current version?

Comment: Most of the GUI stuff now has a button to display it in YAML so you can copy/paste it. Is that not an option? If my memory serves me correctly, you can also just export an existing pipeline as YAML which should capture what you're after.

Comment: @mwilson I can only see 'View YAML' option at task level.  Even in YAML, some of the experience is stored OUTSIDE the yaml definition.  For example, adding run time configurable values using the 'Variables' button when we run a pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

For now the user experience is not supported yet. For now, we have to use hard-code way.

Someone has posted [this feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/901328/select-artifacts-in-yaml-release-pipeline.html) in DC before. You can vote for this open issue and follow it to track the request there. If it gets enough votes, the team would consider it seriously.

Comment: I've clarified the question.  I'm definitely not talking about Intellisense support.  The feature request has it right.  It has my vote.  Without this feature, the teams making the transition to YAML are hard pressed to make changes to the code each time they release a version that's not latest.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding about the Intellisense support. Answer updated :)

Comment: Thank you.  Kindly answer the updated question, if you can.

Comment: Can you share more details about your yaml? I'm not sure about where you put the condition on, and what's the meaning of buildTodeploy variable? That's not a predefined variable i think... Also, the format of variable may affect your pipeline, you can find the correct format [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60314702/setting-build-number-format-conditionally).

Comment: Updated the question with the full YAML.